# Sum of two random variables uniformly distributed on circles

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we have two independent random variables $U_1$ and $U_2$ unfiorm  on 
\begin{align}
S_i = \left\{ (s_1,s_2) \in \mathbb{R}: \sqrt{s_1^2+s_2^2} =r_i \right\} 
\end{align}
respectily. Assume $r_1 \ge r_2$.

Question: How to find the pdf of $U_1+U_2$?

We know that it would be distributed on 
\begin{align}
S_3 = \left\{ (s_1,s_2) \in \mathbb{R}: r_1-r_2 \le  \sqrt{s_1^2+s_2^2} \le r_1+r_2 \right\} 
\end{align}

In other words, show that the sum of two random variables on the circles results in a random variable distributed on an annulus.

The question now is how to find the pdf of $U_1+U_2$?

Can this, for example, be done by using characteristic functions?

Comment: One way is to use the fact that the only distributions  on the circles and the annulus that are invariant under rotations are the uniform distributions. If $T$ is a rotation of $\mathbb R^{2}$ is is obvious that $T(U_1+U_2)=T(U_1)+T(U_2)$ has same distribution as $U_1+U_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not the case.

One way to go about deriving the distribution of the sum is to note that the points may be written $U_i=(r_i\sin\theta_i,r_i\cos\theta_i)$ where $r_i$ are fixed and $\theta_i$ are uniform on $(0,2\pi)$.

Now, write $U=U_1+U_2=(R\sin\theta,R\cos\theta)$. As Kavi has already pointed out, the angle $\theta$ will be uniformly distributed due to rotational symmetry, so we can ignore it and focus on the distribution of $R$.

For $U$ to be uniform on the annulus, $R^2$ would have had to be uniformly distributed between $(r_1-r_2)^2$ and $(r_1+r_2)^2$: just write down the area in the annulus with $R<r$ and divide by the total area expressed in terms of $r^2$.

We now derive the distribution of $R^2$ by use of the relation $R^2=r_1^2+r_2^2+2r_1r_2\cos\phi$ where $\phi=\theta_1-\theta_2$. Note that $\phi$ will also be uniform on $(0,2\pi)$ provided we consider angles modulo $2\pi$.

When $\phi$ is uniform on $(0,2\pi)$, the random variable $X=\cos\phi$ will have probability density $\frac{dx}{\pi\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. So, as you can see, the density is higher around the outer and inner edges of the annulus.

The simplest counter-example comes when $r_1=r_2=r$ and you compute $\Pr[R<r]$. This is the  same as the probability that $\cos\phi<-1/2$, which is $1/3$. If $U$ had been uniform on the disc, it should have been $1/4$.

Comment: I have a quick question. Why is $R^2$ uniform and not $R$?

Comment: @Lisa: Because the area of a disc of radius $R$ is proportional to $R^2$. For a uniform distribution, the probability of a given region is proportional to the area of that region. For a uniform distribution on a disc of radius $r$, the probability density is $1/\pi r^2$ since the area is $\pi r^2$, the likelihood that $R<s$ will be $\pi s^2/\pi r^2=s^2/r^2$, which would make $R^2$ uniform on $[0,r^2]$. For an annulus, it's the same, except the interval is $[(r_1-r_2)^2,(r_1+r_2)^2]$.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how this extends to higher dimensions?  Or should I ask a separate question?

Comment: The approach should generalise to higher dimensions, but the angle between the two vectors $U_1$ and $U_2$ will no longer be uniform: in dimension $n$, it will instead be the angle between two random points on the $n-1$-sphere. And $U_1+U_2$ will still not be uniform as far as I can tell: I'm checking $r_1=r_2=r$ and using that there's a 50-50 chance of the angle between them being above or below $\pi/2$ (with angle given in the interval $[0,\pi]$), which would give a 50-50 chance of $R^2$ being above or below $2r^2$.

Comment: Thanks. In case you are intersted, I posted this question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3198694/let-x-1-and-x-2-be-uniform-on-n-spheres-what-is-the-distribution-of-x